# Getting `-bash: ufw: command not found` error on debian

Tags: debian

I am unable to run any command on debian, I am getting the above error.
Though when I use `sudo` same commands works.

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Why would you ever want to run `ufw` as a non-`root` user?

Comment: @Kusalananda : `ufw` is just an example, I am getting that error for all commands

Comment: @Kusalananda : No you are right, I am getting that error for, those command, who need `sudo` privilege.

Comment: @Kusalananda for docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that the `root` user on your system is set up with a different default `$PATH` compared to that of non-`root` users.

The default paths are specified in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/login.defs`, `/etc/login.conf` or some other file either read by the shell, or by the `login` command. It differs from system to system.

The `ufw` command might, for example, live in `/usr/sbin/`. This directory usually contains tools that only `root` have any use for (many of them might even *require* `root` privileges, such as `ufw`, which is a firewall configuration tool).

There is no real need to have that directory in the `$PATH` of ordinary users.